# Pig Latin translator -- finding consonant clusters.

Tags: java, for-loop, substring, character

I'm making a Pig Latin translator that translates the user's input into Pig Latin. I have it all figured out for when the word starts with a vowel and when it doesn't putting the first letter in the middle. However, when it comes to consonant clusters (the group of characters before the first vowel in the word), I just can't figure out how to lump them together into their own variable. I'm using a for loop to scan the letter for the first variable, and then trying to clump all those strings into it's own variable to then put into the middle of the word.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Mission4
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {   
      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);            

  System.out.println("Please enter word to convert to Piglatin:");
  String userInput = in.nextLine();  

  int firstV = 0;             

  char firstCh = Character.toLowerCase(userInput.charAt(0));

  do
  {

     if (firstCh == 'a' || firstCh == 'e' || firstCh == 'i' || firstCh == 'o' || firstCh == 'u') //if userInput starts with vowel
     {
        String pigTalk = userInput + "ay";
        System.out.println(pigTalk); // adding 'ay' to the end of their input
        System.out.println("Enter another word to convert to piglatin, otherise press \"Q\" to exit.");
        userInput = in.nextLine();
     }

     else //if userInput doesn't begin with vowel 
     {         
        for (int i = 0; i < firstV; i++)
        {                        
           char ch = userInput.charAt(i);

           if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u');
           {               
              firstV = Character.subString(ch);
           }                                                     
        }                                                                   
        String firstCluster = userInput.substring(0,firstV.length);
        String secondCluster = userInput.substring(firstV.length,userInput.length());
        System.out.println(secondCluster + firstCluster + "ay"); //Printing out their piglatin
        System.out.println("Enter another word, or type \"Q\" to exit          program.");
            userInput = in.nextLine(); 
         }
      } while (!userInput.equals("Q")); //Giving user an exit option     
   }
}
```

Can you offer any advice? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To start: 1) The Character class does not have a subString method. 2) ints do not have a length field or any field for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a program with that converts a String into Pig Latin:

```
    import java.io.*;
    class Test1
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter any word: ");
        String s=br.readLine();

        s=s.toUpperCase(); //converting the word into Uppercase
        int l=s.length();
        int pos=-1;
        char ch;

        for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
        {
            ch=s.charAt(i);
            if(ch=='A' || ch=='E' || ch=='I' || ch=='O' || ch=='U')
            {
                pos=i; //storing the index of the first vowel
                break;
            }
        }

        if(pos!=-1) //printing piglatin only if vowel exists
        {
          String a=s.substring(pos); //extracting all alphabets in the word beginning from the 1st vowel
          String b=s.substring(0,pos); //extracting the alphabets present before the first vowel
          String pig=a+b+"AY"; //adding "AY" at the end of the extracted words after joining them
          System.out.println("The Piglatin of the word = "+pig);
        }
        else
          System.out.println("No vowel, hence piglatin not possible");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to organize your code into smaller functions, forming logical units. This makes it easier for both you and others to understand what a program is doing, and what it is doing wrong.

Several mistakes in your program:

- `firstV` is set to 0, and so this loop stops immediately: `for (int i = 0; i < firstV; i++)`
- The loop is broken (doesn't even compile)

What the loop needs to do is iterate from the second character until it finds a vowel.

Here's the corrected main logic extracted to a function, and also a helper function:

```
public String toPigLatin(String word) {
    if (isVowel(word.charAt(0))) {
        return word + "ay";  // actually, wikipedia says you should append "yay", not "ay"
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (isVowel(word.charAt(i))) {
            return word.substring(i) + word.substring(0, i) + "ay";
        }
    }
    return word + "ay";
}

public boolean isVowel(char c) {
    c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}
```

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin#Rules), words starting with vowel should be suffixed `yay` (or `way`). I like your fallback for all consonants. Is that for words like `Grrray`, `Hmmmay`, and `Zzzzay`? Seeing those, I think the `yay` suffix might work better there too. ;-)

Comment: OP used "ay" suffix, I just kept that. But thanks, it's probably worth noting, added a comment for that in the code.